# Laravel 4 attach PDF to email

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-4, email-attachments

I have a problem.  I created a PDF which I attached to an email, but the email is empty. It does not have any attached files.

Here's my code:

```
$pdf = PDF::load($html, 'Letter', 'portrait')->output();
$ruta_pdf = public_path().'/tmp/'.$factura->folio_fiscal.".pdf";
File::put($ruta_pdf, $pdf);

Mail::send('emails.factura', $data, function($message) use ($emisor, $receptor, $factura, $ruta_xml, $ruta_pdf){

$message->attach($ruta_pdf);
$message->from('mail@apscreativas.com', $emisor->nombre);
$message->to('mail2@apscreativas.com', $receptor->nombre);
$message->subject('SUbject');

});
```

I found the solution, the email template can't be empty, must be have a minimal template.

Answer (score 0):

`$ruta_pdf` does not exist within the `Mail::send` call. You'd need to add it to the variables in the `use()` section for it to be present within your mail callback.